# Archive files with .arc extension is growing extremely in oracle database

Tags: oracle, archive

I am using Linux operating system. My application run on Java and Oracle is my Database.
In my `/ora2/DB/archive` folder I have increasing log files written which have occupied 85% of the filesystem now.

I have so many .arc files in `/ora2/DB/archive` with names like `DB1_5218.arc` etc. each occupying atleast 20 MB. I have atleast 100 .arc files written in  a day.

What makes .arc files written?

Why such a Huge load of files in archive folder?

I am new to oracle logs , does too many threads running for a database operation and database not committed, closed or rolledback in the end cause these many files to be written in the archive?

Please help.

Comment: You just have to go back to the questions you have asked earlier and accept some answers if they have worked for you. It doesn't stop them but it definitely discourages potential answerers for fear of not being rewarded.

Comment: You also may want to remove the java tag. It doesn't seem related to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very complete explanation in the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/archredo.htm

Briefly, these are backups of the redo log files generated by database changes. They are used for recovering the database from a media failure. They can also be "consumed" by another database acting as a failover.

Comment: But can these be safely removed from the file system if they are consuming too much space?

Comment: @Phil Since these are REDO files, you should keep them depending on the date in which you want to restore the database from. More older files will give you more recovery time. If you have a purge rule, you can clean these files accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

By taking backup of the archive files you can delete the old archive files from the system and give some space for the new archives.  Deleting from the hard-drive is not enough though, you should clear them using `RMAN`.

1. Delete them from the hard-drive.
2. connect `RMAN>` crosscheck archivelog all;
3. `RMAN>` delete expired archivelog all;
   this way you gave more space to oracle to write the new archive files.